# How do I match cells in one worksheet to another and print a result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

Not new to excel, but new to formulas. I have to say this is killing me.

So what I am trying to do is take strings in one column, check if any of them are in another column of a separate worksheet, and print true/false based on the result.

**END RESULT HOPEFULLY**

```
worksheet1
X - - - Y - - - 
Name1 - False - 
Name2 - True  - 
Name3 - False - 

worksheet2
Z
Name4
Name2
Name5
```

I've tried using `=EXACT(X2,"worksheet2!Z:Z")` but that always returns false.

If anyone has any idea how to help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best tool for it is `VLOOKUP`.

However VLOOKUP needs that the column where you are going to search to be sorted in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, (columns X and Y) then on `Y2` put:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!Z:Z,X2)>0,"True","False")
```